# SSL Let's Encrypt installation not working on NGINX at AWS EC2

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

I have an AWS EC2 Instance with NGINX installed and working, but SSL with Let's Encrypt cannot access.

Nginx Configuration

[image: Nginx Configuration]

Folder /etc/pki/tls with files generated by Let's Encrypt corretly

[image]

AWS Security Group for this EC2 instance

[image]

There ins't load balancer (ELB) involved, Route 53 is sending traffic directly to this EC2 instance.

When I tried to access website over HTTP everything is working, but when I try to connect over HTTPS it's not possible

[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: does anyone listen 443 port at all? What is the output of `netstat -apn|grep 443` after you restart nginx?

Comment: In cases like that please provide configuration as text in your post, not as images.

Comment: Thank yout for the hint, next question I'll do that.

Comment: @Alexey, thanks for your help. I've teste using netstat and saw that 443 port was listening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen you are missing the `ssl` keyword on your `listen` configuration directive.

> The ssl parameter (0.7.14) allows specifying that all connections accepted on this port should work in SSL mode. This allows for a more compact configuration for the server that handles both HTTP and HTTPS requests.

See also examples starting at https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server, such as:

> It is possible to configure a single server that handles both HTTP
>   and HTTPS requests:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen              80;
>     listen              443 ssl;
>     server_name         www.example.com;
>     ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
>     ...
> }
> ```

Also to debug things, you can first connect locally, from the server itself (to itself) using any http client such as `wget`, `curl`,  or `openssl s_client`.  When that works successfully for HTTPS you can then try remotely.

Comment: i would even suggest checking if the port being listened at all prior to checking it with wget/openssl locally. This can be done with `netstat -apn|grep 443`

Comment: @Alexey yes, but any HTTP client will let you know quite fast if it can not connect at all because the port is not in LISTEN state.

Comment: yes, but I would still always first use `netstat` to check to avoid anything in the middle preventing me to connect (and that may cause timeout) like firewall etc. So first make sure that the software is listening to the port at all, then trying to connect with `nc` and so on - that's how I'm used to test

Comment: Hi @PatrickMevzek, thank you man, you were perfect! Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time, I was strugling with this problem some days